# Time Stamping for specific item

Tags: 2013, timestamp

I´m new here! 
I have a list with an status column on SP2013, this can be "User", "Buyer", "GOA". I need to know the amount of days each status was selected; but the status can change multiple times, so I will have "Buyer Date1", "Buyer Date2" and so on for each status.

I already tried creating a calculated column to fill with now when the status changes to any of the values, but it keeps updating every time with a new time. Also tested with modified column used as time stamping and today but it was the same.

I have no access to SP Designer, so its not an option, I only have Infopath.

Any idea to get the time stamping when the status changes

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is lengthy process. But you can achieve your goal using InfoPath form.

1. Create textbox, datetime control in InfoPath.
2. Rule on submit button
3. Compare your selected status and textbox control value
4. If not matched,

   generate date time of now in datetime control. Add selected status in textbox control
5. Publish InfoPath form with generate new column of datetime control in
   list

Comment: thanks 4 the reply. So I have to keep updating the textbox with the last status selected?

Comment: Yes, you have to store last updated status. So you can compare it and get date time on status update.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to get the value saved in the textbox before the form is updated, The save button is actually on the Sharepoint site. Any idea?

Comment: After customizing form in InfoPath, Save button working from InfoPath not from SharePoint site. Try to add custom action rules to Submit option from ribbon.